# C# equivalent of { }.Contains() in VB

Tags: c#, arrays, vb.net

I'm working on a VB => C# translator, and I've run across some VB code that I'm not sure has a direct translation to C#.

In VB you can do something like

```
If {"a", "b", "c"}.Contains("c") Then ...
```

(and let's pretend it something useful that won't always be true)

What I'm wondering is if there is an equivalent of this in C#. The closest thing I can come up with is

```
if (new object[] {"a", "b", "c"}.Contains("c")) { ... }
```

My issue with this is that I have to define the type in C#, meaning I'd have to go with object - since I'm writing a translator, it would need to work equally well for an array of `int`, array of `bool`, array of custom classes, etc. I'm not sure that letting everything be an object instead of a more specific type is a good idea.

Is there a way to let the compiler figure out the type? Something logically like this: (I know this isn't ok, but something logically equivalent to ...)

```
if (new var[] {"a", "b", "c"}.Contains("c")) { ... }
```

so it treats the array as an array of strings and the Contains parameter as a string as well?

Side question: I'm under the impression that the VB code above treats `{"a", "b", "c"}` as an array of `string`. Is this correct? Does the VB code above treat "a", "b", and "c" as objects maybe - if so I'll use object in C# too.

Comment: Use ToString() to convert an object to a string.

Comment: `new [] { ...}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If all the array elements will be the same type, or if they're different types but in a way that satifies type inference, you can use an *implicitly typed array* - like `var` but for arrays, basically:

```
if (new[] { "a", "b", "b" }.Contains("c"))
```

I don't know whether that will be semantically the same as the VB code though.

Comment: Some technical details. The C# compiler will look at the compile-time types of the three entries and determine that `string` is the best matching type. So it will make a `new string[3]` (not an `object[]` as in the question). Then because a `T[]` is an `IEnumerable<T>`, the `Contains` method from LINQ which extends `IEnumerable<>` will be used. This will use the `EqualityComparer<string>.Default` instance which performs an ordinal value comparison. That is, two strings are equal according to that if they are equal as "vectors" of `char` values, sensitive to casing and not considering culture.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding side question:

[fragment from 'Arrays in Visual Basic' on Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/#BKMK_NestedArrayLiterals)

> ```
> Dim numbers = New Integer() {1, 2, 4, 8}
> Dim doubles = {1.5, 2, 9.9, 18}
> ```
>
> When you use type inference, the type of the array is determined
>   by the dominant type in the list of values that’s supplied for the
>   array literal. The dominant type is a unique type to which all other
>   types in the array literal can widen. If this unique type can’t be
>   determined, the dominant type is the unique type to which all other
>   types in the array can narrow. If neither of these unique types can be
>   determined, the dominant type is `Object`. For example, if the list of
>   values that’s supplied to the array literal contains values of type
>   `Integer`, `Long`, and `Double`, the resulting array is of type `Double`. Both
>   `Integer` and `Long` widen only to `Double`. Therefore, `Double` is the
>   dominant type. For more information, see [Widening and Narrowing
>   Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/widening-and-narrowing-conversions).